# how to create invisible and visible forms php

Tags: php, html, forms, visible, invisible

I require a form that is hidden until the user clicks the button and only then the form will be visible, when the submit button is pressed the form would go back to being invisible.

can anyone give me an idea on how implement this, i am assuming this would need to be done using php and ajax calls.

Comment: php works on server, it can't change visibility of a form. Use javascript for this, pure javascript or jquery.

Comment: I would use jQuery for this application.  jQuery has `.show()` and `.hide()` methods you could call making this a fairly simple task.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Did my example help you solve your problem or do you have any additional questions?  Be sure to accept a solution if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

php has nothing to do with visibility neither ajax calls will help you. It is server side scripting . Your page control lies with **javascript** . you have to read about **onClick** events of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

**Note - I should note that this strategy uses jQuery**

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc862bsu/) to a very simple example:

Basically, your form would start off with the CSS property:  `display: none;` and then your show form button would have the following code:

```
$('.form-show').on('click', function() {
    $('.hidden-form').show();
});
```

`.form-show` would be the class of the button being clicked, `.hidden-form` would be the class of the form that is hidden.

Then simply just reverse the process with the submit button:

```
$('.form-hide').on('click', function() {
    $('.hidden-form').hide();
});
```

`.form-hide` is a class on the submit button.

Your form would be something like this:

```
<form class="hidden-form">
    ....
    <button type="submit" class="form-hide">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP being a server-side code probably won't help you here - other than saving the form data to a database.  You COULD use AJAX to be a bridge between javascript and PHP, validating your inputs and returning success or error messages from PHP and such.  This application would be much more complex than my simple solution here.